# Check what ports on a local firewall are open to the outside

Tags: networking, firewall

My computer is on a local network and the network is controlled by a firewall. I am not the administrator of the firewall and do not have access to it. Is there a way to scan open ports on the firewall from my local computer? I need to see what ports are open to outside.

Comment: If you are behind an external firewall, your IP belongs to a subnet and it can probably not be accessed from the internet in any way. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I guess I framed the question badly. I just need to know what ports are open. I need to connect to a remote machine on which I have ssh server. The default ssh port is closed by the firewall. I tried a bunch of other ports but they are all closed. Is there a systematic way to find what ports are open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is probably to ask the system administrator which is the actual port, or in case you can log into the machine somehow (i.e. locally) check with 'netstat -tulpen' or something like that, to identify the ssh port.

If you really want to scan the ports, it is as simple as:

**(*Warning: make sure your system/network administrator is OK with you using nmap)**

```
nmap IP_Of_SERVER
```

Or adding some options...

```
sudo nmap -P0 -sV -A -T4 -p1-5000 IP_Of_SERVER
```

This will show you the status of the ports from 1 to 5000.

You can use another upper limit (default is 1 to 1024). But if they changed the default port, it might probably be in somewhere far enough to make it more difficult to find.

The -sV option makes checks on open ports to determine the actual service running on the port.

The -P0 is to make sure you get to the machine even if ping is filtered, and -A will show you (among other things) the service and version running at each port. The -T4 makes it faster (but also the network admins angrier...).